# AngularJS JavaScript SDK (lb-service.js) & ACL : which property for a related model

Tags: angularjs, models, acl, has-and-belongs-to-many, loopback

I am working on a music application, with genres & subgenres.
We use loopback for the backend, and angularJS for the frontend with cordova & ionic.

I cannot manage to authorize via ACL a request that looks like Genre/:id/Subgenre, for which I have a proprety automatically made via lb-service.js : Genre.subGenre()

The relation's type is "hasAndBelongsToMany" for both models Genre & Sub-genres.

Here is my angular controller that I use in the frontend to do the API request :

```
$scope.genres = [];

Genre.find().$promise.then(function(res) { //this request works : goes to GET /Genres endpoint
  $scope.genres = res;
  $scope.genres.forEach(function(genre) {

    genre.checked=false;
    genre.subgenres = [];
    Genre.subGenres({id: genre.id}).$promise.then(function(r){ //it is this one that doesn't work, GET /Genres/:id/SubGenre endpoint

      genre.subgenres = r;
      genre.subgenres.forEach(function(s){
        s.checked=false;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

here is the code in lb-service.js that provide the Genre.subGenre() property:

```
    // INTERNAL. Use SubGenre.genres() instead.
    "prototype$__get__genres": {
      isArray: true,
      url: urlBase + "/SubGenres/:id/genres",
      method: "GET"
    },
```

and here is the code in the genre model to authorize the acces to the API for the Genre.subGenre() property :

```
"acls": [
  {
    "accessType": "*",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "DENY"
  },
  {
    "accessType": "EXECUTE",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$authenticated",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "subGenres" // this is to authorize Genre.subGenre(), doesn't works => 401 error.
  },
  {
    "accessType": "EXECUTE",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$authenticated",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "find" // this is to authorize Genre.find(), it works
  }
```

It looks like it is the property that is not correct, because when I do the same thing to authorize the Genre.find() request, it works.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured out that I just needed to change in the ACL :

```
"accessType": "EXECUTE"
```

into

```
'"accessType": "READ"
```